# What does this equation do?

Tags: summation

I'm doing a computational competition, which asks me to solve the following equation based on certain inputs. However, my maths classes so far have not covered what the big E symbol does. Could someone please explain it to me?

$$\text{Matth}(n,p)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(n,p+k)f(2p,k)$$

Comment: Summation symbol.

Comment: And? I've never seen it before. What does it mean?

Comment: You can find an easy introduction to a sigma notation here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sigma-notation.html

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{i=4}^6 a_i=a_4+a_5+a_6$$ Similarly, $$\prod_{i=4}^6 a_i=a_4\cdot a_5\cdot a_6$$

Comment: The sum of all k from 1 to infinity in the latter expression. (Well after I edited your post using LaTeX, I found that someone has done it, so ignore mine.)

Comment: So evaluate the expression for every value of k from 0 to infinity, and then add them up?

Comment: @billytheme Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

A basic example:

\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{5}\frac 1k&=\frac 11+\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14+\frac 15\\
&=\frac {137}{60}\end{align}

Can you see how it works from this example?